# How to solve point on line problems with PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis, common-table-expression, topology

I found an interesting question about point on line problems to be solved with Java on stackoverflow. The post has been heavily down-voted and deleted (rightfully so!) because obviously someone just wanted others to do his homework. Anyway, I thought it would make a really nice PostGIS example. The aim is to not use plpgsql / control structures as there are plenty of examples already out there - I want to write *queries*. So the "parameters" are in a CTE (go ahead, stone me for it :D ... or put the code into a function and share). Here we go.

**Problem Statement**
You are given coordinates (0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) (1,5) (1,4) (3,5) as input.

1. Check if the given points lie in the same line.
2. Given 2 points find the points in between them. Input: (0,0) (0,3), Output: (0,1) (0,2)
3. Given a point, find the points on the largest line - in terms of the points it contains - passing through that point. Input: (0,1), Output: (0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (0,3)

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
WITH param AS (
    SELECT
        ARRAY[ST_MakePoint(0,0), ST_MakePoint(0,1), ST_MakePoint(0,2), ST_MakePoint(0,3), ST_MakePoint(1,5), ST_MakePoint(1,4), ST_MakePoint(3,5)] AS points
), ps AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS id, tmp.p
    FROM (
        SELECT UNNEST(points) AS p
        FROM param
    ) AS tmp
)
-- if every point triple forms a straight line, all points form a straight line
SELECT bool_and(ST_Area(ST_MakePolygon(ST_MakeLine(ARRAY[ps1.p, ps2.p, ps3.p, ps1.p]))) = 0)
FROM ps AS ps1, ps AS ps2, ps AS ps3
WHERE ps1.id < ps2.id
    AND ps2.id < ps3.id;
```

---

2.

```
WITH param AS (
    SELECT
        ARRAY[ST_MakePoint(0,0), ST_MakePoint(0,1), ST_MakePoint(0,2), ST_MakePoint(0,3), ST_MakePoint(1,5), ST_MakePoint(1,4), ST_MakePoint(3,5)] AS points,
        1 AS p1_index,
        4 AS p2_index
), ps AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS id, tmp.p
    FROM (
        SELECT UNNEST(points) AS p
        FROM param
    ) AS tmp
)
SELECT ST_AsText(ps.p)
FROM ps, param
WHERE ST_Intersects(ps.p, ST_MakeLine(points[p1_index], points[p2_index]))
    AND ps.id NOT IN (p1_index, p2_index);
```

---

3.

```
WITH param AS (
    SELECT
    ARRAY[ST_MakePoint(0,0), ST_MakePoint(0,1), ST_MakePoint(0,2), ST_MakePoint(0,3), ST_MakePoint(1,5), ST_MakePoint(1,4), ST_MakePoint(3,5)] AS points,
    2 AS p_index
), ps AS (
    SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER())::INTEGER AS id, tmp.p
    FROM (
        SELECT UNNEST(points) AS p
        FROM param
    ) AS tmp
), straight_triple AS (
    SELECT ps1.id AS p1, ps2.id AS p2, ps3.id AS p3
    FROM ps AS ps1, ps AS ps2, ps AS ps3
    WHERE ST_Area(ST_MakePolygon(ST_MakeLine(ARRAY[ps1.p, ps2.p, ps3.p, ps1.p]))) = 0
        AND ps1.id < ps2.id
        AND ps2.id < ps3.id
    ORDER BY ps1.id
), candidate_line AS (
    -- the point could be on more than one line
    SELECT p1s || p2 || p3 AS p_indexes, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY cardinality(p1s || p2 || p3) DESC) AS n_points_rank
    FROM (
        -- group up points by point pairs they form a straight line with
        SELECT array_agg(p1) AS p1s, p2, p3, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY (array_agg(p1))[1] ORDER BY cardinality(array_agg(p1)) DESC) AS length_rank
        FROM straight_triple
        GROUP BY p2, p3
    ) AS pair_intersection, param
    WHERE length_rank = 1 AND (p1s || p2 || p3) @> ARRAY[p_index]
)
-- pick the longest line, or any from multiple longest lines
SELECT ST_AsText(points[i])
FROM (
    SELECT UNNEST(p_indexes) AS i
    FROM candidate_line
    WHERE n_points_rank = 1
) AS indexes, param;
```